# Java string parsing with different regex to split

Tags: java, string, parsing

```
str="Tick for symbol .ISEQ-IDX descriptor id 1 timestamp_sec 20130628030105 timestamp_usec 384000;EXCH_TIME 1372388465384;SENDING_TIME  0;PRICE 3957.890000;MIC XDUBIND;"
```

I dont have any control on changing the format of how this string is created.

I tried this but I cant really get the values of first keys "Tick for symbol","timestamp_sec" etc.

Not only in this specific string but I was curious about how to parse a string with multiple regex splits. Any help will be appreciated.

```
   String[] s = line.split(";");
    Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
          String[] split = s[i].split("\\s+");
          for (String string2 : split)
          {
             //Adding key value pair. to a map for further usage. 
           m.put(split[0], split[1]);
          }

    }
```

**Edit**
**Desired output into a map:**
(Tick for Symbol, .ISEQ-IDX)
(descriptor id, 1)
(timestamp_sec,20130628030105)
(timestamp_usec,384000)
(EXCH_TIME,1372388465384)
(SENDING_TIME,0)
(PRICE, 3957.890000)
(MIC, XDUBIND)

Comment: What characters do you want to split on

Comment: What is your desired result depending on given string?

Comment: Initially thought to split on semicolon but cannot get all the key value pairs split buy that. or by a space character but again there are spaces in key's as well.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Updated the desired output.

Comment: My suggestion is to keep all possible values of keys then parse input string (if it possible).

Comment: If you know the keys in advance then you can look for them in succession. A regex search in a loop should be quick enough.

Comment: How do you know it is ("Tick for symbol" : ".ISEQ-IDX") and not ("Tick" : "for"), ("symbol" : ".ISEQ-IDX") ?

Comment: @Jirka-x1 Since I know what should be the output. offcourse ("Tick" : "for") doesnt make much sense.

Comment: Splitting on anything here is unlikely to produce the results you want. It seems like you're looking for mattern matching.

Comment: Do you know the set of keys? Are they always ordered the same way? Are all of them always present?

Comment: are they positional? always with the same position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following? You specify a list of key-value pattern pairs. Keys are specified directly as strings, values as regexes. Then you go thru this list and search the text for the key followed by the value pattern, if you find it you extract the value.

I assume the keys can be in any order, not all have to be present, there might be more than one space separating them. If you know the order of the keys, you can always start `find` on the place where the previous `find` ended. If you know all keys are obligatory, you can throw an exception if you do not find what you look for.

```
    static String test="Tick for symbol .ISEQ-IDX descriptor id 1 timestamp_sec 20130628030105 timestamp_usec 384000;EXCH_TIME 1372388465384;SENDING_TIME  0;PRICE 3957.890000;MIC XDUBIND;";

    static List<String> patterns = Arrays.asList(
        "Tick for symbol", "\\S+",
        "descriptor id", "\\d+",
        "timestamp_sec", "\\d+",
        "timestamp_usec", "\\d+",
        "EXCH_TIME", "\\d+",
        "SENDING_TIME","\\d+",
        "PRICE", "\\d+.\\d",
        "MIC", "\\S+"
      );


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

            for (int i = 0; i<patterns.size();i+=2) {
                String key = patterns.get(i);
                String val = patterns.get(i+1);
                String pattern = "\\Q" +key + "\\E\\s+(" + val + ")";
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(test);

                if (m.find()) {
                    map.put(key, m.group(1));
                }
            }
            System.out.println(map);

        }
```

Comment: I was trying to do this by str.indexOf(str, fromIndex) but this was looking complicated than what you gave me.

Comment: Yes, this solution looks good. I did it in a similar way, but without the List, I just used Pattern. :)

Comment: Note that this is probably good enough, but as the values have not been specified, it could be that you find a key in a value. Double keys may also be an issue. So this solution may not be the right solution for everyone. As said, probably is for you :)

Comment: Sure, I don't know the exact specs. (BTW it does not search for a key alone, but for key+space+value pattern). It is easy to modify based on the exact specs. If the order of keys is fixed and all are obligatory, one can also match one big pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a regex will help you here, whoever designed that output String clearly didn't have splitting in mind.

I suggest simply parsing through the String with a loop and doing the whole thing manually. Alternatively you can just look through the String for substrings (suck as "Tick for symbol"), then take whatever word comes after (until the next space), since the second parameter always seems to be one words.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Pattern` class from java.util.regex package, described step by step in this [java Regex tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
private static final Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("^Tick for symbol (.*) descriptor id (\\d+) timestamp_sec (\\d+) timestamp_usec (\\d+);EXCH_TIME (\\d+);SENDING_TIME  ?(\\d+);PRICE (.*);MIC (\\w+);$");

private static String printExtracted(final String str) {
  final Matcher m = splitPattern.matcher(str);
  if (m.matches()) {
    final String tickForSymbol = m.group(1);
    final long descriptorId = Long.parseLong(m.group(2), 10);
    final long timestampSec = Long.parseLong(m.group(3), 10);
    final long timestampUsec = Long.parseLong(m.group(4), 10);
    final long exchTime = Long.parseLong(m.group(5), 10);
    final long sendingTime = Long.parseLong(m.group(6), 10);
    final double price = Double.parseDouble(m.group(7));
    final String mic = m.group(8);
    return "(Tick for Symbol, " + tickForSymbol + ")\n" +
         "(descriptor id, " + descriptorId + ")\n" +
         "(timestamp_sec, " + timestampSec + ")\n" +
         "(timestamp_usec, " + timestampUsec + ")\n" +
         "(EXCH_TIME, " + exchTime + ")\n" +
         "(SENDING_TIME, " + sendingTime +")\n" +
         "(PRICE, " + price + ")\n" +
         "(MIC, " + mic + ")";
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument " + str + " doesn't match pattern.");
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Using `group` instead of `replaceAll` as it makes more sense and and is also faster.

Comment: why do you use `m.replaceAll`? Wouldn't `m.group(i)` be enough?

Comment: bad habits I suppose, will change it now. In my tests using group made the code run 5-10x faster than using replaceAll